# Unable to connect to Docker's SQL Server instance that died after opening a few connections

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server instance on Debian's Docker.

It died after I tried to open 7 connections to it from C# app with Entity Framework.

What could've happened? I cannot find anything about this error

> The connection timeout has expired. The time limit has expired while attempting to use the reconciliation confirmation made before logging in.
>   This could be due to a failure to reconcile before logging in or that the server could not respond in time. Time consumption when trying to connect to this server: [before logging] initialization = 9; agreeing = 14996;
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Image used: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

```
Server Name: myserver
Error Number: -2
Severity: 11
State: 0

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Comment: your question is so unclear also the link you put as image is not an image it goes to azure container.

Comment: @Halilİbrahim ``sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Edit image as Image that runs under docker.

Comment: have you checked SQL Server Service is it alive ?

Comment: Well, I restarted it and now Im able to connect to it, but it is very slow and throws ``. An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The connection has been broken and recovery is not possible. The client driver tried to recover the connection at least once, but none of these attempts succeeded. Increase the value of the ConnectRetryCount element to increase the number of recovery attempts. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)``

Comment: Its all about SQL server google deeper for settings